# Back button to middle mouse button

Tags: x11, kde, mouse, xmodmap

I would like to map "Back" button (xev shows it as "button 7") of my mouse (A4Tech X-7) to act as a middle mouse button. Is there a way to do this? I'm lost in google, finding only how to map buttons to keyboard shortcuts with xbindkeys and etc.

- OS: Centos 6.3 (x86_64)
- DE: KDE 4.3.4

P.s. I can switch (with xmodmap) "Back" button with middle button with no problems, but is there a way to have both them act as a middle mouse button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot map two physical buttons to the same logical button. All you can do is swap the buttons (`echo 'pointer 1 7 3 4 5 6 2' | xmodmap -`). This is a low-level limitation of X11. As stated in the documentation of [`XSetPointerMapping`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man3/XSetPointerMapping.3.xhtml):

> However, no two elements can have the same nonzero value, or a BadValue error results.

The best you can do is to use a program like `xbindkeys` to send a fake button 2 press when button 7 is pressed. In `.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xdotool mousedown 2"
  b:7
"xdotool mouseup 2"
  b:7 + Release
```

Comment: That's what I've thought. Anyway, thanks for nice reply ;)